# Is there a technology capable of disabling the whole of Earth's satellitle network?

Tags: technology, communication, satellites

Machine-based communication (and navigation) relies extensively on satellites. In the future, with the massification of 5G, more and more reliance will be put on satellites (e.g. the *Internet of Things*), with other technologies (like fiber optic) becoming less prominent.

Inspired by a sci-fi movie I watched the other day, I wonder whether there is currently a technology (even if in development stage) capable of rendering the **whole** of Earth's satellite network useless in a fairly quick way. You would imagine this could have catastrophic consequences on Earth (and, connecting back to the sci-fi movie, would definitively give an antagonist alien race mastering that technology a significant advantage when attacking Earth).

I know there are tools to do [radio jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_jamming). However, that is still very localised (geographically as well as in terms of radio bandwidth). I'm more interested in a technology that could render **the whole (Earth) network** useless.

Comment: Are you trying to build such systems. If not it sounds like a question for worldbuilding.SE (or better yet suggest a terrorism.se on area 51 (; )

Comment: If there are the tools that exist - who is going to tell **you** ?

Comment: @joojaa Of course I am. That's why I am asking in this deep web forum, where no one can find me ¬¬.

Comment: How technological is technological? You could quite handily achieve this by detonating a large amount of shrapnel in low-earth orbit. It'd simply be a matter of detonating enough of it before the major space-borne powers can stop you.

Comment: Welcome to the site luchonacho, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] Interesting (and scary) question, I look forward to answers.

Comment: There is a bit misconception here. Wireless is based on antenna towers. Satellites are only used by GPS which is a receive-only protocol. In other words EMPing all satellites in orbit is barely going to affect the internet. Cross-ocean communication is done by undersea glassfiber lines.

Comment: An alien race could deploy their own satellites over the equator to shoot down every geostationary satellite as it passes by. If it's small enough, such a satellite will be virtually undetectable except at the instant of firing. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Well, I guess that's fine, as long as its fairly simple and quick, such that humans could not react sufficiently quickly to stop the attack.

Comment: @nzaman You mean something like a killer UAV/drone/robot/ship that just shoots an anything that moves?

Comment: @luchonacho Well, at the moment we don't have any truly reliable anti-missile defence systems. Least of all ones that could intercept a rocket heading to orbit. Plus, if you wreck enough satellites they add to the cloud of shrapnel that would then wreck the rest of them. It's also somewhat of a permanent solution...

Comment: Well, they'd probably have an AI on board that could recognise the profile of a satellite. Firing at space junk just wastes energy and reveals the shooter's location

Comment: It's called an exoatmospheric nuke - or maybe a few of them.

Comment: Uh, neither IoT nor 5G (a [mobile network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_network) tech!) need satellites for anything - satellite internet connection is way too slow and power-hungry. Only the navigation part is often done via GNSS, communication is not affected by taking down satellites.

Comment: Not technology per se, but a sufficiently strong solar emission could also wipe them out (along with earth's magnetic field, and us)

Comment: Machine-based communication mostly relies on cell towers and wi-fi, which rely on undersea cables. 5G means more cell towers. And by the way there isn't ***a*** satellite network, there are lots of networks (that use their own satellites each), but that doesn't matter if you're going to destroy *all* satellites.

Comment: @Bergi: Please make this an answer. Disabling satellites will disable GPS & TV, but not mobile phones or Internet.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's not an answer to the question, though it is a valid criticism of the premise on which the OP based it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and that is called a frame challenge, an allowed type of answer.

Comment: Are you looking for something more sophisticated than *bullets*?  Because I think bullets would do the trick, if you use enough of them.

Comment: Another question that sounds like it was written by an aspiring terrorist... :P

Answer (score 41):

Yes, [Kessler Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome)

In particular:

> The Envisat satellite is a large, inactive satellite with a mass of 8,211 kg (18,102 lb) that drifts at 785 km (488 mi), an altitude where the debris environment is the greatest—two catalogued objects can be expected to pass within about 200 meters of Envisat every year—and likely to increase. It could easily become a major debris contributor from a collision during the next 150 years that it will remain in orbit.

It wouldn't be instantaneous but if you exploded a few suitable targets such as Envisat you could fill the relevant sections of space with destructive fragments that then cause a cascade of strikes into other targets. Space could become a very hostile environment in a few years and remain that way for decades.

Comment: Interesting! With enough clutter orbiting Earth, we could be trapped inside, as it might be too risky to get a ship out without risking a collision. Looks like we are very vulnerable at the moment.

Comment: I was imagining that someone might launch a giant glitter bomb.

Comment: Kessler Syndrome would be the most reliable method, but it would take some careful planning if you wanted to take out EVERY satellite. Satellites orbit the Earth at a range of altitudes and inclinations (angles relative to the equator). You would probably need at least a handful of collisions/explosions at various locations in order to reliably destroy every satellite. If you had months or years to wait for debris to spread and interact, you could probably get away with fewer initial collisions/explosions.

Comment: That could prevent the launch of new satellites, but existing satellites in geosynchronous orbit wouldn’t be affected.

Comment: Launching a truckload of small ball bearings into elliptical orbit that crosses the orbits of GPS satellites as well as geo-stationary satellites would be a pretty effective way to initiate the Kessler syndrome and mess up the most important satellite services in-use.

Comment: @MikeScott Why do you say that? With the right spread of debris no satellite anywhere in earth orbit is safe.

Comment: This is incorrect. Kessler syndrome applies only to a very specific orbit which makes launch difficult, but will be harmless to the vast majority of existing satellites.

Comment: @forest: Launch difficulties are often mentioned as the main issue because the relative speed difference between a (launching) vehicle in a suborbital trajectory and shrapnel in an orbital trajectory is massive, thus causing massive collisions. However, that isn't the _sole_ issue with the "shrapnel field" of Kessler syndrome. Another big factor is the fact that this can cause a chain reaction, and this is why the answer addresses OP's question: a few destroyed satellites can snowball into a majority of satellites being taken out. Maybe not all, but still a significant amount.

Comment: Yep, particularly if the initial impacts are deliberately designed to accelerate the cascade.

Comment: Space is very big, though[citation needed]

Comment: @Flater It only affects a very specific orbit, which most satellites are not in.

Comment: @forest: By definition of what Kessler syndrome is, it's more "successful" in the orbit where most satellites are. The odds of a sustained chain reaction depends on the density/amount of items to have a chain reaction between.

Comment: @Flater Please see http://braino.org/essays/kessler_syndrome_is_over_hyped/

Comment: So the idea that even a significant amount would be destroyed, sufficient to completely disable the Earth's satellite network, is complete baloney. **This answer is nothing more than the repetition of a common popsci concept misinterpreting the space industry's (justifiable) worries.** Kessler syndrome is bad for sure, but it would not be the end of satellite technology, just an economic disaster.

Answer (score 10):

All at once, none that I know of. But you can always count on the good old human party trick:

## Blow it up

The classical Bond's movie move is to send a few dozens missiles and take down enough of the network to accomplish your goal. Let's take GPS, for reference. GPS work with <s>geo-synchronous</s> satellites broadcasting an universal time set on an atomic clock<sup>1</sup>. 
*It it bothers you, skip that part:*

> Your device receive signals from those satellites that tell them *when* the satellite broadcasted it. It deduces the time each signal took to come from each satellite, thus allowing to triangulate your position (triangulate as in, you need at least 3 to pinpoint your position in space, otherwise, you end up with a sphere or a circle and it's not convenient).

What I'm getting at is that the system is highly dependent on its network. If you take out enough of the grid, you create at least a "no-service" zone (per Earth obscuration), or you make it completely ineffective.

My guess would be that a few missiles strikes would do quite a bit of damage to your satellite network. <sup>1</sup> (Not sure *which* missiles are able to reach satellite orbit if any though. But it's well within our reach, as well as any sci-fi race bothering visiting us)

Other option:

## EMP

**This one is highly hypothetical and should be taken with lots of care.** *EMP* (electro-magnetic pulse) is a common sci-fi trope. Basically, a very powerful electro magnetic field disrupt electronics, and it's pretty nasty on computers. I think I remember *Call of Duty MWII*<sup>2</sup> used a nuke exploding in orbit to disable satellites. Now, an explosion happening into the void of space does not end up in a big ball of fire *a la Death Star*. If I'm not mistaken, it instead produce electro magnetic radiation (among probably other things. I'm stressing <sup>1</sup> on this point).

Thing is, radiations and electro magnetic fields are probably something to expect in space. (Radiation is a given, EMP... maybe <sup>3</sup>). So I wouldn't be surprised if satellites were protected against natural causes for this. But it might be worth looking into the theory.

*This answer does not support any kind of attempt to take down satellites and I hereby decline responsibility if anyone manage to make sense of this thoroughly uninformed ramble and somehow devise the weapons to enact it.*

<sub>1: No expert here, anyone feel free to correct me if I misunderstood something / made a mistake.</sub>
<sub>2: See why I said **lots of care**? [sarcasm]*Very reliable* source for sure [/sarcasm]</sub>
<sub>3: I mean, I know there *is* electro magnetic radiation in space, as even Earth has an electromagnetic field. The thing is, I don't know if they are powerful enough to fry electronics. Slight disgression here, that would need to be answered by someone actually knowledgeable about this.</sub>

---

**Edit 1:** As pointed in comments, I was mistaken about GPS using geo-synchronous satellites. Thanks to [Zeiss Ikon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/57454/zeiss-ikon) and [user71659](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/44004/user71659) for their clarifications.<sup>4</sup>

**Zeiss Ikon**: "GPS are not geosynchronous. They're at 20,200 km, which is close to half of GEO height, and some are in highly inclined orbits rather than equatorial."

**user71659**: "GPS is designed to be difficult to blow up by having six separate orbital planes. [...] On top of that, there's literally more GPS satellites in orbit than the system can handle. The system needs 24, it can handle 31 at the same time, and there's 40 usable. The extras are simply on standby as spares. Compare that to GLONASS which is 1 away from losing global coverage and Galileo which 4 short for global coverage (delays & a launch mishap)."

It makes sense some network are designed to be robust since [GPS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) was originally a military project under the name **Navstar GPS**. Including system redundancy is done precisely to counter-act the loss of a few satellites. If we follow user71659 comment, you'd need to blow up at least 17 satellites to impede the system (to which extent, I don't know).
user71659 also suggested geo comsats would be an easier target to disable. Unfortunately, I'd need a little disambiguation as a research results are numerous, so I suggest you ask directly our fellow terrorist.SE user.

Furthermore, the **Kessler effect** have been pointed out several times in other answers. I didn't include it in mine for two reasons.
First, I didn't know the name of the phenomenon at the time, though it would be an obvious byproduct of exploding satellites.
Second, satellites using differents orbits at differents altitudes, I suppose it would not be "just" blowing up some satellites and would requires some maths beforehand to ensure enough remaining orbital devices would be hit in an acceptable time-frame (before the lost ones are replaced). Probability is an hard mistress though, and she commands that, if a satellite and debris have a chance to collide, they eventually will.

<sub>4: Let's give credit where it's due.</sub>

Comment: GPS are not geosynchronous.  They're at 20,200 km, which is close to half of GEO height, and some are in highly inclined orbits rather than equatorial.

Comment: GPS is designed to be difficult to blow up by having six separate orbital planes. It trades off some accuracy for that. It is more robust than the other systems, EU Galileo, Russian GLONASS and Chinese BeiDou, all of which use 3 orbital planes. On top of that, there's literally more GPS satellites in orbit than the system can handle. The system needs 24, it can handle 31 at the same time, and there's 40 usable. The extras are simply on standby as spares. Compare that to GLONASS which is 1 away from losing global coverage and Galileo which 4 short for global coverage (delays & a launch mishap).

Comment: Okay, bad example then. Thanks for the information, I will edit accordingly

Comment: @Nyakouai I'd say geo comsats would be the most vulnerable. Already [happened before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_IV).

Comment: @user71659 Let me know if I messed up again, but I think this time, the part about blowing stuff up is correct.

Comment: In CoD MV2 it was an EMP not a nuke

Comment: @atayenel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_2#Story It is a nuke (double checked, it's explicitly stated in other languages) but the result is an EMP.

Comment: Nyakouai & @atayenel You're both half correct.

*all* nuclear weapons generate EMP. It doesn't matter whether it detonates in space or not. The crude bombs we dropped on Nagasaki and Hiroshima in WW2 generated an EMP pulse (and five or six other interesting things).

The key thing is not space's vacuum, but distance from the ground. Nukes detonated near ground level have most their EMP hit the ground. Detonating a single powerful enough nuke in space can take out the entire USA's electrical grid.

MW2's nuke was a regular nuke, just detonated high enough so only the EMP reached the USA.

Comment: Nuclear weapons generate five or six different interesting effects, each with different reach: the explosion, the heatwave, the shockwave, the EMP wave, the high intensity short-lasting short-penetration radioactivity (think, "dead in 48 hours" radiation), the low-intensity long-lasting deeply-penetrating radioactivity (think, "cancer in 20 years" radiation) - I'm not an expert, so I probably am missing alot of important details, and likely have several things wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The most obvious solution is the high-altitude nuke. Watch this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcTrOGS3TyE

Just to summarize: nuclear blast sends a lot of charged particles at hight speed away. Earth's magnetic field redirects that back-and-forth, and since moving charges means current, and alternating current induces current in wires, it kills a lot of sensitive electric stuff, including satellites, telephone lines, electric cables, and everything connected to the end of those. So there will be a lot of collateral damage, only use this if your story supports it.

Comment: Yes, this exactly. We happen to know that this is quite effective at destroying satellites, as [we've unintentionally destroyed several of them this way already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish_Prime#After_effects). :)

Comment: The high altitude nuke is probably not high enough to affect satellites in geosynchronous orbit, because most ballistic missiles can't reach the required altitude.

Answer (score 8):

### A rocket armed with a grenade launcher and 2000 grenades

There are about 2000 satellites. Therefore, just make a rocket, launch it into space, and have it start firing grenades into each satellite individually. Satellites are designed to survive radiation and vacuums, not explosions. Apparently, they are structurally very fragile to save weight.

Note that you do not need to *chase* the satellites. That would take a lot of fuel. Instead, you can just aim the grenades at the satellites. There's (almost) no air resistance in space, so you can fire as far as your accuracy and precision permits.

If you got enough cash, you could even fire or throw the grenades yourself. This would be a *lot* more expensive, since you need to launch a human into space and get a *lot* closer to the targets (since humans are not good at aiming), all on top of the tyranny of the rocket equation. However, that's a small price to pay to be the person to destroy all of Earth's satellites by dual-wielding grenade launchers in space, in my opinion.

Comment: In was going to downvote because the logistics of getting enough shooters into space is daunting, but then i saw that the shooter is dual wielding, so that's an upvote.

Comment: @bukwyrm The idea is that there would only be one shooter that takes down all 2000 satellites.

Comment: depending on the fire rate of the (hopefully full-auto?) grenade launchers the shooter is dual wielding, it may not even be necessary to put her into orbit - a brief stint above atmosphere may be sufficient, like with an ICBM. Great stuff.

Comment: @bukwyrm Well, having a human fire the grenades would take much longer, since you need to get close enough for a human to aim. For an automatic rocket, you might only need elevation, not orbital velocity.

Comment: Might want separate missiles for LEO, MEO, and GEO, as the altitudes are so vastly different.  Or maybe one that fires off rounds at lower orbits as it continues to higher, maybe when boosters separate.

Comment: @user3294068 yeah, doing it on the way would make sense. How would it be to launch a projectile that changes orbit though?

Comment: *hard would it be

Comment: @bukwyrm Oh wait, nvm, you probably want orbit. Otherwise, your range will be terrible. While in orbit, projectiles fired will automatically also be in orbit.

Comment: This should probably go without saying, but the distances and relative velocities are so high that the odds of hitting a satellite with an unguided projectile are almost exactly 0%, there can be relative velocities between different orbits in excess of 10 km/s (i.e. between equatorial and polar orbit), try hitting something passing by a few hundred km away at mach 30. Usually we don't even have enough certainty of the exact location of a satellite to be able to reliably hit it even with absolutely perfect accuracy and timing, knowing where it is to within say 10 m is not good enough.

Comment: @BlakeWalsh hmm, what if we glue magnets to the grenades?

Answer (score 3):

Both the US and old USSR had anti-satellite weapons in development before agreeing a treaty to play nice in space. I don't know if the results were ever considered viable weapons but I can't believe they would have deleted the blueprints. The Chinese actually shot at one of their own satellites a few years back.

So if we can do this now, then your postulated aliens with the technology to cross interstellar space should have no problems targeting a few thousand sittings ducks moving in well ordered and predictable orbits.

A shotgun makes a very capable weapon in orbit, with the advantage that the pellets don't fall to ground after 50m.  If you can use laser, maser, emp/x-ray bursts or even old fashioned kinetic weapons it shouldn't be an impossible task. The magazine of the A-10 Thunderbolt carried 1350 rounds, so with perfect marksmanship you'd only need 4. Actually you could afford quite a few misses!

Comment: [The U.S. Navy shot down a defunct U.S. NRO satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Burnt_Frost) before the Chinese did it, actually, so, yeah, it's pretty well known that the technology is still around. They just used the existing Aegis Ballistic Missile Defense system to shoot it down with an SM-3.

Answer (score 2):

Some well-known hypotheticals:

- Have *something* crash into *something* to start the [Kessler Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome).
- Build a big, ground-based laser or maser and start to take potshots at satellites. The [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-satellite_weapon#U.S._programs) stopped Star Wars before it got there. The [Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASAT_program_of_China#Directed-energy_weapons) might have something like this.
- Come up with a set of malware to attack the ground control and to send destructive commands, like "spend all the maneuvering fuel get onto collision course with another sat." The problem, those control systems are rather hard.

Comment: And the Soviet actually launched a prototype [orbital laser weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyus_(spacecraft)) (which crashed back in the atmosphere because of a tiny computer bug, and then Perestroika happened)

Comment: @Eth Wow, epic fail. "For technical reasons, the payload was launched upside down. It was designed to separate from the Energia, rotate 180 degrees in yaw, then 90 degrees in roll and then fire its engine to complete its boost to orbit. The Energia functioned perfectly. However, after separation from Energia, the Polyus spun a full 360 degrees instead of the planned 180 degrees. When the engine fired, it slowed and burned up in the atmosphere over the south Pacific Ocean." Oops.

Answer (score 2):

A solar flare is capable of doing just that. A strong enough one hitting the earth directly would knock out any satellite facing the sun. So while it may not hit EVERY satellite, it would get more than half - remember the satellites are high above the earth.

So, if an alien race had large solar flare level technology, it would likely destroy a large portion of our satellites. Give that the majority of our space communications are over the northern hemisphere (most 1st world counties and land mass are there), this would basically destroy most of them if positioned appropriately.

See for instance:
https://sciencing.com/solar-flares-affect-communication-23537.html

Comment: While radiation from solar flares does indeed induce radio blackouts and cause some satellites to fail entirely, most satellites are designed to survive flares and CMEs.  The biggest danger to satellites from flares and CMEs is that increased solar activity expands the Earth's atmosphere, increasing drag substantially for objects in Low Earth Orbit, causing them to deorbit sooner than planned.  A Carrington level event is, of course, beyond the radiation hardening that current satellites are designed to survive.

Comment: Sounds like the question then is could an alien race realistically produce a Carrington type flare to knock out satellites. Because their range is closer and could be localized one target at a time shots they might need less energy than that.

Comment: As i think more a potentially better solution if we really are considering alien level tech would be a dozen ships (i assume they take more than 1) with cloaking tech and simply blow them up 12 at once and then another 12 shortly after. Because we can't see the ships it would take too long to respond before they were all gone. As for cloaking, lots of researchers are working on nanostructures  and left handed materials that are close to achieving cloaking with our own tech level. So we know that stuff is possible. It isn't quite a quick as maybe the op wants but would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Neither 5G nor IoT depend on satellites at all. Satellites are used primarily for Navigation (GPS, GLONASS) and in the public sector, television.

#### What is 5G

5G is broken down into two different radio bands.

- 600 MHz to 6 GHz
- 24–86 GHz

Anything above 2GHz(2000MHz) will be mostly blocked by hard surfaces, and have very short travel distances. Those 24GHz+ signals would be blocked by a piece of paper.

#### What is IoT

IoT stands for Internet of Things, its a buzzphrase commonly used to refer to devices that, pre-2010, were not connected to the internet, such as fridges, ovens, lights, televisions.

IoT seems to be a large marketing point for 5G, but as we have already defined earlier, the range of high speed 5G will be no longer than wifi, and in most cases shorter. Therefore these devices would function perfectly fine on normal wifi.

#### Now, lets look at what you REALLY want

Can you jam every radio signal on earth? Yes, and no. Lets look at some points.

- High frequency radio waves, are hard to *JAM*, because their range is so short, therefore the jammers range will be just as short.
- Low frequency radio waves, are much easier to JAM, and this could be done by simply placing satellites surrounding the earth that broadcast waves across the entirety of the low-spectrum.

Is there a way, then to jam those high frequency signals? Maybe, radiation from an extremely powerful source, could interfere with those signals. For example: The Sun.

If you could find a way to remove earth's [magnetosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere), then the radiation from the sun would be enough to knock out all communications on earth, it would even interfere with hard wired links(not fiber)!

Unfortunately, that also has the undesirable side effect of destroying all life on the planet, fairly quickly. :)

Comment: Thanks! Great clarifying answer.

Comment: All life, or all surface life? There's some pretty interesting stuff living deep in the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if your aliens can cross light years of space, they might have some as-yet-unexplained way to cause a massive solar flare or coronal mass ejection.

Comment: If you could explain the some as-yet-unexplained way the answer would substantially improve

Comment: This is basically the plot of [Sunstorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunstorm_(novel)).

Answer (score 1):

Since the technology stack you describe likely will depend on the Internet Protocol, it might be possible to just corrupt the routes the packages take: by targeting the Border Gateway Protocol (BGP, which is the protocol the big routers at your Internet Service Provider speak among each other to find the shortest route for a packet to its destination) from a few strategically positioned routers under your control (positioned in the logical network structure, not necessarily physically). Even though the satellites are not routers, they form one possible link between routers ... and in the scenario you describe, they may as well have become routers.

Side note: I think here's a flaw in your story: satellites will not become the most prominent data link, just because they are so far away from earth. The light speed is a hard limit and data will take considerably more time to go over a satellite link than a cable. It really is no fun to play a fast game via satellite link just because of a two-way latency ("ping time") of at least 690ms (see http://www.dslreports.com/faq/2001). But okay, let's set that aside for your story.

The gist of the attack would be to advertise on the lower network layers (where BGP is spoken) that *you* have got the shortest route to every destination, therefore persuading all routers not under your control to send all packets via your routers ... where you can drop them into nirvana. This has happened already, see e.g. https://www.securityweek.com/google-services-inaccessible-due-bgp-leak -- a Nigerian Internet Service Provider blocked not only their own users from using Google, but blocked wide parts of the internet by advertising that the shortest routes to Googles servers are through Russia, Nigeria and China. There are countermeasures that could be taken, but these are, in essence, manual: other router admins have to mark the routers where the problematic BGP data originate from as untrustworthy.

Now, if you have enough big routers under your control (your own, hacked by you, however you gained control...), you might be able to pull this off for an extended period of time, essentially dividing the network of networks that the internet is into single networks that cannot communicate with each other anymore.

Disclaimer: I'm only a computer scientist, not a network security engineer. I recommend to fact-check this story on an SE about network security.

Comment: It's... unlikely. BGP is a pretty naive protocol, as it assumes that everyone knows what they are doing, so indeed out of the box you can get stupid stuff done. However, precisely because it's naive, experienced admins will configured their BGP gateways to NOT blindly trust others, instead having various white-lists etc... you may catch some admins unaware, but if they are competent the problem within minutes to hours.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That just raises the routers you need to "own" up to ... a quarter of the total? I think? It isn't that inconceivable that in the scenario described a global company owns that many central routers (especially if these all run on satellites, where it is harder to get into the market), making all others depend on that company.

Comment: Today, about each ISP has its own BGP routers. That's hundreds of actors. And no, they will not run on satellites: the speed of light makes it impractical, and nothing goes faster than light.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree on that latter point (see the side note in my answer).